# How to use listing multicols in tabularx environment?

Tags: tabularx, multicol

I want to insert multicol in the tabular environment. Here is **MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}




\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|c|}\hline 
\textbf{Q. No.} &  & \textbf{marks}\\ \hline 
  26. &  A polynomial of odd degree with real coefficients must have \begin{enumerate}
      \item at least one real root.
      \item no real root.
      \item only real root.
      \item at least one root which is not real.
  \end{enumerate} & 4\\ 

    26. &  Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Which of the following equals $\operatorname{trace}(A^2B^2)$ \begin{enumerate}
 \item 
      $(\operatorname{trace}(AB))^2$
\item $\operatorname{trace}(AB^2A)$
\item $\operatorname{trace}((AB)^2)$
\item $\operatorname{trace}(BABA)$
  \end{enumerate} & 4\\ \hline 
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This gives :

[image]

But I want to like this:
[image]

When I use :

```
26.   Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Which of the following equals $\operatorname{trace}(A^2B^2)$
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $(\operatorname{trace}(AB))^2$
        \item $\operatorname{trace}(AB^2A)$
        \item $\operatorname{trace}((AB)^2)$
        \item $\operatorname{trace}(BABA)$
    \end{enumerate}     

\end{multicols}
```

This gives an error. How can I resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experience no problems with using `multicols`. I suggest, though, that you load the `enumitem` package to modify the appearance of the `enumerate` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\trace}{trace}

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\usepackage{tabularx,multicol}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep,wide,leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|c|}
\hline 
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Question} & \textbf{marks}\\ \hline 
26. &  
A polynomial of odd degree with real coefficients must have 
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
      \item at least one real root.
      \item no real root.
      \item only real roots.
      \item at least one root which is not real.
\end{enumerate} 
\end{multicols}
& 4\\ 

27. &  
Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Which of the following equals $\trace(A^2B^2)$ 
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $(\trace(AB))^2$
\item $\trace(AB^2A)$
\item $\trace((AB)^2)$
\item $\trace(BABA)$
\end{enumerate} 
\end{multicols}
& 4\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want @ Mico.